# change relayhost depending on mx for destination domain

Tags: postfix

I am used to configure transport_maps so I can control which relay to use for specific domain.

I would like to change the relay or the route depending on the resolved MX, because a lot of domain are moving to office365 or google,  so I would like to be able to select a specific relay if the domain MX is for example aspmx.l.google.com

is it possible to set this in transport_maps ?

thanks for clarification and enlightenment.

I just tried this as per this [post](https://serverfault.com/questions/735906/configure-postfix-to-route-to-specific-ip-based-on-the-recipient-mx-record) :

```
smtpd_recipient_restrictions = ..., check_recipient_mx_access hash:/etc/postfix/mx_access,...
```

but it does not produce any relay

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK, I get to fix my own mistake, the order of smtpd_recipient_restrictions options is important, so one have to place check_recipient_mx_access in the first options, so smtpd known it has to route the message a special way BEFORE it get definitively accepted or rejected.